# Why is this error coming? I have node.js installed already

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

So, I type `npm init` in the terminal on Visual Studio Code - Insiders, and this comes out:

```
npm init
npm : The term 'npm' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or 
if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ npm init
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (npm:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I do have the latest version of node.js and VSC Insiders on my PC. Any help will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following solutions:

1. Add `C:\Users\<USERNAME>\AppData\Roaming\npm` to your PATH environment variable (replace  with your username). To access the environment variables follow this:

- Open "Start" menu
- Search for "Environment variables"
- Select "Edit the system environment varibles"
- Select "Environment varible..." in the bottom right
- Double click the PATH variable in the upper box (User environment variables)

2. Do the same but add "C:\Program Files\nodejs", or more in general to the directory where Node is installed

Answer (score 0):

It is because the system cannot able node packages.
You should try setting the path of downloaded node package in your system environment variables.

```
C:\{{ your system path to nodejs }}\nodejs\
```

To the end of your Path variable on the "User variable" section of the Environment Variables on the System Properties.

Comment: I'll try doing that. Thanks